# I have to create a Time scale

Tags: variables, field

I have a fields STARTDATE and a FREQUENCY (1Month, 2Month, 3Month,...)
I need to create a program of activities in base a STARTDATE+FREQUENCY
In some case I need to 12 value (1 per month), in other case 2 value (1 of 6 month)
Some tips?
Thanks
Angelo

Comment: Welcome on stackoverflow. Please be more specific. What is your environment/programming language/platform? What is your exact problem? Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) on how to ask a good question.

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you have and what you want exactly ?

Answer (score 1):

I work with SQL Server 2008/2012 and sql language.
I would like to create a table (or view) looks like this:
Item firstdate offset next1      next2     next3      next4
IT1 07/21/2016 180   01/21/2017
IT2 2016/07/20 30    2016/08/20 2016/09/20 2016/10/20 2016/11/20
IT3 2016/08/20 60    2016/10/20 2016/12/20
IT4 08/01/2016 360
Thanks